# Spring + Prometheus + Grafana: Err reading Prometheus: Post "http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9090: connect: connection refused

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, grafana

Hello I have an app in Spring Boot and I am exposing some metrics on Prometheus. My next goal is to provide these metrics on Grafana in order to obtain some beautiful dashboards. I am using docker on WSL Ubuntu and typed the next commands for Prometheus and Grafana:

```
docker run -d --name=prometheus -p 9090:9090 -v /mnt/d/Projects/Msc-Thesis-Project/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

```
docker run -d --name=grafana -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana
```

Below I am giving you the Prometheus dashboard in my browser and as you can see, everything is up and running. My problem is in Grafana configuration where I have to configure Prometheus as Data Source.

[image: Prometheus Dashboard]

In the field URL I am providing the http://localhost:9090 but I am getting the following error:

> Error reading Prometheus: Post "http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9090: connect: connection refused

I've searched everywhere and saw some workarounds that don't apply to me. To be specific I used the following: http://host.docker.internal:9090, http://server-ip:9090 and of course my system's IP address via the ipconfig command http://<ip_address>:9090. Nothing works!!!

I am not using docker-compose but just a prometheus.yml file which is as follows.

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:

  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'Spring Boot Application input'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 2s
    scheme: http
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['192.168.1.233:8080']
        labels:
          application: "MSc Project Thesis"
```

Can you advise me something?

[image: Grafana Dshboard]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the docker inspect command to find the IP address of the Prometheus container and then replace the localhost word with it.

Comment: Wow, I didn't exepected this. Seems like it worked with localhost earlier, but now your answer helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can simply replace `localhost` with `prometheus` in the URL field of Grafana.

Tested it on my device just now and using `localhost` I received the same error as you did. When I replaced the URL with `http://prometheus:9090` and clicked on save it did work as intended.

Comment: Awesome...Works for me.

Comment: Glad to hear that it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the same host for Prometheus and Grafana docker containers;
In this case, setting up `http://host.docker.internal:9090` as the Prometheus datasource will do the trick:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- It works for https://stackoverflow.com/a/74061034/4841138
- Also, if you deploy the stack by docker compose and all dockers are in same network, you can do that:

  URL: http://prometheus:9090

In above, `prometheus` is the domain name of the prometheus docker, which can be resolved by all dockers within same network.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33606177)

Answer (score 0):

Set net flag to use host network and access Prometheus using localhost or 127.0.0.1:

```
docker run -d --network host --name=prometheus ...
```

Answer (score 0):

neither of those worked for me, running on ubuntu with current latest versions of prometheus and grafana. what did the trick was to run grafana with this host: `sudo docker run --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway -p 3000:3000 ${imagename}` and then use "http://host.docker.internal:9090" as target

Answer (score -1):

I'll suggest you to use docker-compose, which better supports in DNS resolving and your issues of localhost will get resolved.